# SSMS collecting several variables from string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and SSMS, and I'm trying to collect several variable values from one string.

This method only works when there is ONE variable:

String:

```
There are 2 dogs walking the park in the summer and there are 4 dogs walking the park in the winter
```

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@txt, CHARINDEX('are', @txt), 
                    CHARINDEX('dogs', @txt) - CHARINDEX('are', @txt) + LEN('dogs'))
```

The result here will be 2. I'm looking for a way to get either the 2 or the 4, or as total of 6.

If my information is incomplete, please leave a comment.

Comment: So are you *actually* saying you want to get the sum of all the numbers in a string use T-SQL...? Which, honestly, has nothing to do variable or SSMS? *Side Note: SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for almost an entire year now, you should raelly be looking at upgrade paths or using a supported version if you're learning the language.*

Comment: That is what i want yes. The numbers can be different. Thats why i called it a variable.

Comment: A [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is something *completely* different.

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler in more recent, SUPPORTED versions of SQL Server.  In SQL Server 2008, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), 'There are 2 dogs walking the park in the summer and there are 4 dogs walking the park in the winter') as rest,
             convert(varchar(max), null) as val, 1 as lev
      union all
      select stuff(v.val, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', v.val + ' ') - 1, ''),
             left(v.val, patindex('%[^0-9]%', v.val + ' ')), lev + 1
      from cte cross apply
           (values (stuff(cte.rest, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', cte.rest) - 1, ''))) v(val)
      where cte.rest like '%[0-9]%' 
     )
select val
from cte
where val is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10f00673a26548f9d02be410bf05c766) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to separate the string into it's separate parts based on where spaces are, then find out which are integers, and then `SUM` those. AS you're using an unsupported version of SQL Server, you don't have access to `TRY_CONVERT`, which would make this *way* easier, however, you can at least use [`DelimitedSplit8K`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function), which results in something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(int,DS.Item))
FROM (VALUES('There are 2 dogs walking the park in the summer and there are 4 dogs walking the park in the winte'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(V.YourString,' ') DS
WHERE DS.Item NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```